# Suma de dos cantidades sin el típico Button "Calcular"

Tags: java, android

Tengo un ejemplo con dos EditText un TextView y un botón, el programa simplemente suma las dos cantidades al hacer click en el botón y las muestra en el TextView, me gustaría que una vez se comience a introducir cantidades en cualquier de los EditText se mostrara el resultado de la suma sin necesidad de utilizar el botón calcular, es decir, que lo hiciera el mismo programa automáticamente.

Espero haberme explicado bien, agradecería ayuda para conseguirlo.

Aquí dejo el ejemplo en el que estoy trabajando:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

int cantidad1 = 0;int cantidad2 = 0;int Resultado = 0;

private EditText et_Cantidad1, et_Cantidad2;
private TextView tv_Resultado;
private Button bt_Boton;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate ( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView ( R.layout.activity_main );

    et_Cantidad1 = (EditText) findViewById ( R.id.editTextNumber );
    et_Cantidad2 = (EditText) findViewById ( R.id.editTextNumber2 );
    tv_Resultado = (TextView) findViewById ( R.id.textView );
    bt_Boton = (Button) findViewById ( R.id.button );
}
public void sumar(View view){
    int n1, n2, suma;
    n1 = Integer.parseInt ( et_Cantidad1.getText ().toString () );
    n2 = Integer.parseInt ( et_Cantidad2.getText ().toString () );
    suma = n1+n2;
    tv_Resultado.setText ( "La Suma es: " + suma );
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar `TextWatcher` para detectar cuando el contenido dentro de los `EditText` cambiò, cada vez que cambie llama el mètodo `sumar()`, ejemplo:

```
et_Cantidad1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
 
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
   }
 
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, 
     int count, int after) {
   }
 
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, 
     int before, int count) {
     sumar(); 
   }
  });
 
 }
```

Algo importante que debes considerar es que creaste un mètodo `sumar()`, pero no es necesario que reciba una View como paràmetro a menos que lo estes llamando desde un layout .xml, por lo tanto es suficiende definir el mètodo `sumar()` de esta forma:

```
//public void sumar(View view){
public void sumar(){

    int n1, n2, suma;
    n1 = Integer.parseInt ( et_Cantidad1.getText ().toString () );
    n2 = Integer.parseInt ( et_Cantidad2.getText ().toString () );
    suma = n1+n2;
    tv_Resultado.setText ( "La Suma es: " + suma );
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, reto conseguido ;-)